# what does the flatten means in ndimage.imread()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, scipy

when I want to make a picture into a matrix: I use Scipy`s imread to read image

```
from scipy import ndimage
a=ndimage.imread("1.jpg",flatten=False)
```

so when should the flatten be true or when should the flatten to be false?

Comment: Have you bothered reading the doc?

Comment: I have read the doc,the doc says that flatten make the picture into grey

Comment: then what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

as per code doc define in module`s function imread **[github repo](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/misc/pilutil.py)**

or **[document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html)**

**imread** function take three arguments

1. **name** : str or file object
       The file name or file object to be read.
2. **flatten** : bool, optional
       If True, flattens the color layers into a single gray-scale layer.
3. **mode** : str, optional
       Mode to convert the image to, e.g. `'RGB'`.  See the Notes for more
       details.

As per your Question flatten is use to read image in RGB or gray-scale

if flatten is false then it read in RGB

if flatten is true then it read image in Gray-scale

by default flatten value is false

For **Use** :

In Image processing after reading image always need to convert image to gray-scale
  so flatten is the direct option to read image in gray-scale or in Rgb